# Any specific reason why localtime throws warning with struct tm* & stat* , in linux ?

Tags: c, linux, time, stat, localtime

I have this simple code (part of a project) :

```
void displayFileProperties(struct stat* file,char*  outputProperties , char * path)
{

    struct tm* time;

        // code 
        // code
        time = localtime(&file->st_mtim);


        // code 

}
```

Where eclipse keeps throwing me a warning :

```
passing argument 1 of ‘localtime’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]   main.c  /ex4    line 340    C/C++ Problem
```

Any idea how to fix this ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`st_mtim` is a struct timespec (seconds and nanoseconds). You want `st_mtime`.

Comment: Alan please note that Eclipse shows an error this time (after adding the `e`) : `
Field 'st_mtime' could not be resolved main.c /ex4 line 342 Semantic Error
`

Comment: Eclipse is wrong :-) Seriously. Smash it in the head until it respects your authority. Or add the eclipse tag to this question, or ask a separate followup question... this is just an Eclipse bug report now.

Comment: I wish :) but it won't compile with that lovely `e` at the end

Comment: I haven't used Eclipse so I don't know how hard it is to force it to just feed the damn file to gcc. How about saving the file and compiling it with gcc yourself?

Comment: You're so right ! I makefile-d it terminal with `make` and it works great . No idea however why the eclipse is yelling ...:) thanks again

Comment: As a workaround, you can just use the seconds portion of the struct timespec: `st_mtim.tv_sec` which should be equivalent to `st_mtime` (in fact, `st_mtime` on my system is a macro that expands to `st_mtim.tv_sec`)

Answer (score 1):

Completely changed answer:

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Make sure you #include these headers:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

2) Cast your pointer to "const"

```
time = localtime((const time_t *)&file->st_mtime);
```

3) Post back what happens

=====================================================

ADDITIONAL SUGGESTIONS:

1) Please read these two links:

> - [C stat struct does not have st_ctime field but only st_ctim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403963/c-stat-struct-does-not-have-st-ctime-field-but-only-st-ctim)
> - http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat
>
> Since kernel 2.5.48, the stat structure supports nanosecond resolution
>   for the three file timestamp fields. Glibc exposes the nanosecond
>   component of each field using names of the form st_atim.tv_nsec if the
>   _BSD_SOURCE or _SVID_SOURCE feature test macro is defined. These fields are specified in POSIX.1-2008, and, starting with version 2.12,
>   glibc also exposes these field names if _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined
>   with the value 200809L or greater, or _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined with
>   the value 700 or greater. If none of the aforementioned macros are
>   defined, then the nanosecond values are exposed with names of the form
>   st_atimensec. On file systems that do not support subsecond
>   timestamps, the nanosecond fields are returned with the value 0.

2) Clearly, the makefile (that "works") has a #define that Eclipse doesn't, or vice versa.

Probably either/both  _POSIX_C_SOURCE and/or _XOPEN_SOURCE.

Run this command to see what exists in the command line (makefile?) environment:

`gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | less`

3) Please post back what you find!

Comment: localtime *returns* a (pointer to) struct tm. Its argument is pointer to time_t.

Comment: @paulsm4: Thanks but I tried that , my only conclusion is that the Eclipse platform doesn't like `st_mtime` . A simple `makefile` however , runs it like a pro.

Comment: @ron - It's not Eclipse per se ... but something in the Eclipse compilation environment is definitely "doing something".  My guess is that "something" might be "_POSIX_C_SOURCE": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403963/c-stat-struct-does-not-have-st-ctime-field-but-only-st-ctim

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use this instead:

```
time = localtime(&file->st_mtime);
```

Note the added 'e' at the end. st_mtim is a timespec, with 'e' added it's a time_t (what you need).

Comment: :Thanks , but I've tried this already and got `Description Field 'st_mtime' could not be resolved main.c /ex4 line 340 Semantic Error
` . Looks like the type is not known , and I even tried the headers `#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
` and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Eclipse:
Field st_mtime could not be resolved (semantic error)

Fixed the issue in Eclipse by right-clicking the project, choose Index->"Freshen All Files"

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct tm* alarmTime(void);

int main(){
    printf("Hour :%i\n", alarmTime()->tm_hour);
    printf("Minute :%i\n", alarmTime()->tm_min);
    return 0;
}

static struct tm* alarmTime(void){
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm* ptm;
#ifdef HAVE_LOCALTIME_R
    struct tm tmbuf;
    ptm = localtime_r(&now, &tmbuf);
#else
    ptm = localtime(&now);
#endif
    return ptm;
}
```